# Manually creating route alias with custom DirectRouteProvider causes "Multiple actions were found that match the request" error

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a service using the ASP.NET WebApi framework. I want to support URI extension based content negotiation, so I have added the following to the service intitialization code:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json");
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "application/xml");
  }
}
```

For this to work, I need to create two routes for each controller action (I am using attribute based routing exclusively):

```
[Route("item/{id}/details")]
[Route("item/{id}/details.{ext}")]
[HttpGet]
public ItemDetail[] GetItemDetails(int id)
{
  return itemsService.GetItemDetails(id);
}

[Route("item/{name}")]
[Route("item/{name}.{ext}")]
[HttpPost]
public int CreateItem(string name)
{
  return itemsService.Create(name);
}
```

This is ugly and makes the code unnecessarily long, so I researched a way to automatically add the route with the extension whenever the normal route is created. I came up with a custom implementation of `IDirectRouteProvider` that I can use when registering the route attributes:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new AutomaticExtensionRouteProvider());
```

The custom route provider looks as follows:

```
public class AutomaticExtensionRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
{
    protected override IReadOnlyList<RouteEntry> GetActionDirectRoutes(
      HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
      IReadOnlyList<IDirectRouteFactory> factories,
      IInlineConstraintResolver constraintResolver)
    {
        var result = base.GetActionDirectRoutes(actionDescriptor, factories, constraintResolver);
        var list = new List<RouteEntry>(result);
        foreach(var route in result.Where(r => !r.Route.RouteTemplate.EndsWith(".{ext}")))
        {
            var newTemplate = route.Route.RouteTemplate + ".{ext}";
            if (!result.Any(r => r.Route.RouteTemplate == newTemplate))
            {
                var entry = new RouteEntry(null, new HttpRoute(newTemplate,
                    new HttpRouteValueDictionary(route.Route.Defaults),
                    new HttpRouteValueDictionary(route.Route.Constraints),
                    new HttpRouteValueDictionary(route.Route.DataTokens)));
                list.Add(entry);
            }
        }
        return list.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

The problem is that this approach *mostly* works... but I have found it to fail in one case: **when the last part of the route is an unconstrained parameter**. So for the controller methods of the previous example, `GetItemDetails` works, but `CreateItem` method does not and throws the following:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
CreateItem on type FooBar.Api.Controllers.ItemsController
CreateItem on type FooBar.Api.Controllers.ItemsController
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
```

I realize what can be causing the error: a random string matches both the `{name}` and the `{name}.{ext}` pattern, so the WebApi engine chokes when trying to select the appropriate route. **But then, how come that it does actually work when explicitly specifying the two routes in attributes??** To my understanding, the route that I create in the `AutomaticExtensionRouteProvider` class is identical to the route that is created with an explicit attribute (and debugging seems to confirm so).

So, what's going on? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, ended up figuring out it by myself.

Turns out that routes have a numeric **precedence** assigned, that the WebApi routing engine uses to decide which route to actually use in case of conflict. Routes created automatically for the same action have always different precedence, but the route that I was creating manually had the same precedence as the existing one!

So the solution is to add the following to the `GetActionDirectRoutes`, immediately after the `new RouteEntry` statement:

```
entry.Route.DataTokens["precedence"] = 
    ((decimal)route.Route.DataTokens["precedence"]) - 0.1M;
```